# how to send JSON string multiple times

Tags: java

I have made a java class sending JSON object to server and getting a response , however now i want to execute this request say 5 no of times , so that i can send the request to the server 5 time with the same JSON object .

Can you please help me with this ? is it possible with Thread executers ?

Comment: add some code to get more quality answers.

Comment: Call the method 5 times.

Comment: calling the method 5 times , again the for loop will not perform it in parallel i need parallel .

Comment: post your code with your qustion that u have tried

Answer (score 1):

Because of pour quality of your question aswer is also very general.

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
     request.send(jsonObject);
    }
```

Another method using threads. It can be extends to use executor instead of loop.
in another file

```
public RequestTask implements Runnable{
  private JsonObject o;
  public RequestTask(JsonObject obj){
     this.o = obj;

  }
  public void run(){
      request.send(jsonObject);
  }

}

for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
  Thread task = new Thread(new RequestTask(jsonObject));
  task.start();
}
```

Instead of last loop :

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
      Thread task = new Thread(new RequestTask(jsonObject));
      executor.execute(task);
    }
    executor.awaitTermination();
    System.out.println("Finished all threads");
```

for using it in main class

```
public class ClassWithMain{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
          Thread task = new Thread(new RequestTask(jsonObject));
          executor.execute(task);
        }
        executor.awaitTermination();
        System.out.println("Finished all threads");
  }

}
```

Comment: for loop runs one by one isnt ? i think some thread is required .

Comment: It can be :) but much more simpler is using simple loop.

Comment: Thanks for the Reple , however what is RequestTask in this ? my code is :

Comment: Rafik ;), Please accept my answer if it was helpful for you, thanks in advance

Comment: Is a private class that extends runnable interface. If you want to use it firing in thread you have to provide that simple class and create task using that class. That class is in my first code listing, look at it ;)

Comment: i have a class with main {} so you want me to write another class ?

Comment: Yes, you can do it it into your class with main but then you have change that RequestTask as private static class, but you can do it simply in another file  ;) that might be simpler and cleaner solution, so create file with name RequestTask, and paste there class with public accessor and then use it into your main class ;)

Comment: ok , i didnt understand this "and paste there class with public accessor and then use it into your main class ;) " ?? can you pelase let me know the steps . please

Comment: 1. create new file RequestTask.java
2. paste class RequestTask from my listing to RequestTask file
3. use it in your main class

Comment: ok thanks , in my main class ok what about the logic i wrote to send the JSON oject to server ? do i need to write the logic in forloop mentioned by u ?

Comment: Yes, i think. You have to

Comment: but this doesnt resolve my purpose :(( , i put my log also in the code its not executing number of times , only once it executed :(

Comment: It's strange. If you have my loop in your code it is impossible to ommit it without exception. But to help you with that please provide more code in you question.